# Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection timed out (OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110).Why am I getting this error?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-http

I am getting the error below when trying to load data from server using http package.

**The Error :**
Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection timed out (OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110), address = xerarchsolutions.com, port = 40636

**What I did so far**

1. Added internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml
2. Created and added network_security_config.xml
3. Added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` in AndroidManifest.xml

**My network_security_config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">xerarchsolutions.com</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">commondatastorage.googleapis.com</domain>
</domain-config>
```

Also I tried running my app on different devices and emulator from Android 8 to 12. Sometimes, only sometimes it works. What am I doing wrong here? If there something else I need to provide to solve this issue please let me know. I have been stuck for 2 days now. So Please help me.

**This is my http post function**

```
getTopics() async {
http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(topicsURL));

String data = response.body;
var topicList = jsonDecode(data)['topics'];
for (var i = 0; i < topicList.length; i++) {
  topics.add({
    'id': topicList[i]['tp_id'],
    'name': topicList[i]['topic'],
    'selected': false,
  });
}}
```

Comment: Show your code to begin with.

Comment: Added the code of http request

Answer (score 0):

because no internet connection is received to the targeted system or device

check this line in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: As I mentioned I have already did this.

Comment: is the issue came after taking release build or debug

Comment: after taking debug build